# Getting records with offset and orderBy in activeJDBC

Tags: java, activejdbc, javalite

**I get duplicate records using:**

```
List<Post> postList = Post.findAll().limit(Long.valueOf(request.queryParams("limit"))).offset(Long.valueOf(request.queryParams("offset"))).orderBy("id desc");
```

When I remove orderBy it works fine.

- **First pull:** limit is 3 offset is 0
- **Second pull:** limit is 3 offset is 4 `//I get duplicates on second
  pull`

Why is it so?

**update:**

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` mediumint(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text,
  `details` text,
  `created_at` text,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userImage` text,
  `url` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_id` text NOT NULL,
  `postImageUrl` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=243 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `lt9vgms366ueidoa`.`post`
(`id`,
`title`,
`details`,
`created_at`,
`username`,
`userImage`,
`url`,
`article_id`,
`postImageUrl`)
VALUES
(<{id: }>,
<{title: "Test"}>,
<{details: "Test"}>,
<{created_at: }>,
<{username: "Test"}>,
<{userImage: }>,
<{url: "Test"}>,
<{article_id: "121"}>,
<{postImageUrl: }>);
```

**Request mapping:**

```
get("/get_data_on_scrollEnd", (Request request, Response response) -> {
    System.out.println("ON SCROLL END -- LIMIT: "+ request.queryParams("limit") + " " + "OFFSET: "+ request.queryParams("offset"));
    List<Post> postList = Post.findAll().limit(Long.valueOf(request.queryParams("limit"))).offset(Long.valueOf(request.queryParams("offset")));
    System.out.println("///////////////////////");
    log.info("PAGINATION: " + postList);
    System.out.println("///////////////////////");
    return postList;
}, new JsonTransformer());
```

The returned `List<Post> postList` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Because your offset on the second pull needs to be offset + limit.

Also, you might want to look into a [Paginator](http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/snapshot/org/javalite/activejdbc/Paginator.html) which was built to page through results on web pages.

On the off-topic, the way you parse long values from the parameters is vulnerable to runtime exceptions if your customers start messing up your URL.

Comment: Actually, on the first pull, the limit is 3 and offset is 0

Comment: Setting offset+limit on second pull doesn't fetch data at all. I have about 6 records in DB. Offset on second pull is 3(offset) + 3(limit)

Comment: post the structure and contents of your table here, so I could replicate it.

Comment: also, turn on logging: http://javalite.io/logging and post the SQL generated when you are running the app

Comment: updtated the question. Added log4j as in the docs. How do I generate sql while running the app?

Comment: Please, see my earlier comment. Additionally, in earler comment, I asked for content of table. Please, do not include a picture of a table, include a DDL to create a table, and SQL to fill it with data.

Comment: There is no sql generated. Added log4j

Comment: Updated the question with create and insert sql

Comment: Fixed the issue. It was actually the issue with `orderBy` Thanks ipolevoy :)

Comment: glad it worked out for you. Given that this framework is about 8 years old, I would really be surprized if there are logical errors :)